# Does the Dell XPS 9350 work with the WD-15 dock?

Tags: dell-xps

I have a Dell XPS 9350. I'm curious to know if the Dell WD-15 USB-C 180W dock will work with it **and** provide power to the laptop. I've heard conflicting reports on this pairing, and would like to know if these units will work together.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it wouldn't come with a 180W AC power adapter if it wasn't intended to also power a notebook. :)

From [Dell's description of that dock](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/products/Docking/productdetail.aspx?c=ca&l=en&s=que&cs=caque1&sku=450-AEUO):

> Featuring a powerful DisplayPort over USB Type-CTM cable, with the Dell Dock you can quickly connect your laptop or tablet to *a single data and power source*